# The training process of a conditional GAN

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, convolutional-neural-networks, computer-vision, generative-adversarial-networks

For example, consider a dataset like MNIST. I give the conditional vector to produce only the number $7$ for both the generator and discriminator. In the following scenarios, what will the discriminator classify as fake or real:

The generator produces realistic numbers other than $7$, such as a realistic number $9$ ?

The samples from the MNIST dataset that are not the number $7$ (i.e., other numbers) ?

Comment: Hi @abcd and welcome to AI Stack Exchange! If possible, editing this post to change the title to a specific question may aid in getting answers more quickly. Thank you for posting, and we look forward to more of your questions in the near future!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you mean how to label the image and class inputs since the discriminator can reasonably output either "real" or "fake" labels for either of those inputs, and you generally want to be training with an imperfect discriminator.

In both your scenarios the correct ground truth for training the discriminator is "fake", although it may be better to think of it as "incorrect" in the case of mislabeled real inputs.

You may also reasonably decide not to train with mislabeled real images. They are not necessary, and although they *might* improve the discriminator training, that's not going to make a difference for the MNIST digits task.

You shouldn't train with deliberately mislabeled generator images, either. If the generator accidentally makes a "1" when you asked it to generate a "7", then you should label ground truth as "fake" for training the discriminator and "real" for training the generator, *plus* in both cases you should include the attempted "7" as input to the discriminator alongside the generated image

Comment: I'm actually trying to understand the training process of cGAN and how the discriminator will classify in those cases. That's what I'm trying to ask

Comment: @abcd - what the discriminator's actual output would be? That is covered in the first paragraph. It would not be consistent.

Comment: What do you mean by 'not consistent'? Didn't you assign the correct labels to the discriminator in the implementation? For example, images generated by the generator that are not correlated with the conditional vector, no matter how realistic they are, will be considered fake. Similarly, real images from the dataset that are not correlated with the conditional vector will also be considered fake. This is my point

Comment: @abcd That is what the rest of my answer after para 1 already says - what the target labels are. You then commented that you want to know what the actual output will be. That is different. The discriminator does not immediately output the target output during training. It slowly learns and becomes better at it over time as part of the training process. It is not really possible to predict in advance whether the discriminator's output will be "correct" at any particular stage of training.

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: I thought that in the original conditional GAN (cGAN), the discriminator only classified images as fake or real. Does it also verify if the images match the condition label ?

Comment: @David it classifies the whole input data, the image plus the condition label. There isn't a separate verification AFAIK, although that could be a valid architecture. However, something has to check the condition holds, the generator otherwise has no way to receive feedback whether it has matched the constraints

Comment: @NeilSlater, _something has to check the condition holds_ so this means the original cGAN lacks this capability. I'm not sure if the generator sometimes ignores the conditional label, and the discriminator also ignores the conditional label

Comment: @David The original cGAN **does** have this capability, built into the discriminator's bool output (it is only true for generations that are in the target dataset and match the condition). Otherwise there would be no point to adding the condition. It's simply not something that would be named or published. Yes sometimes the generator and/or discriminator will give wrong answers, because they are not perfect

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, I think the discriminator will classify those realistic numbers as real because they look real and can fool the discriminator.

As for the second case, I also think the discriminator will classify them as real because the numbers are from the dataset.